# How do I return related models based on IDs in two columns in pivot table (two foreign keys)?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a pivot table set up with the following columns:

```
table - contributions
=====================
id          - int, pk
user_id     - int, fk
resource_id - int, fk
linked_id   - int, fk
...
```

This basically creates a many-to-many relationship between users and resources. Now, the thing is, `linked_id` is also a foreign key which points to the ID in the resources table. In most cases, `linked_id` will just be null and won't be a problem. But sometimes, I want a contribution to be linked to a user, a resource, and one other resource.

In my Resource model I have the following code:

```
public function contributions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Contribution');
}
```

But this won't return anything if I'm calling this on a Resource which has its ID in the linked_id column. Is there some way to return all the rows/relations when the resource's ID is found in either the resource_id or the linked_id column? (Somehow has a second $foreignKey value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my `contributions` function inside my `Resource` model like so:

```
public function contributions()
{
    return DB::table('contributions')
        ->where('resource_id', '=', $this->id)->orWhere('linked_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->join('resources', function($join) {
            $join
                ->on('resources.id', '=', 'contributions.resource_id')
                ->orOn('resources.id', '=', 'contributions.linked_id');
        })
        ->groupBy('contributions.id')
        ->select(
            'contributions.id', 'contributions.description', 'contributions.created_at', 'resources.id AS tileId', 'resources.name AS tileName',
            'users.id AS userId', 'users.username')
        ->get();
}
```

The linked contributions will now show up in both models without having to create two entries for each link.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, options:

1) create a custom query where you retrieve the Resource, join the contributions table where you match resource_id or linked_id on the current id from the Resource object.

something like:

```
SELECT R.* 
FROM resources AS R
INNER JOIN contributions AS C ON (
        C.`resource_id` = R.`resource_id`
    OR  C.`linked_id`   = R.`resource_id`
)
WHERE R.`id` = {$Resource->id}
GROUP BY R.`id`
```

2) create a second relation method, linkedContributions, which matches the linked_id column.

```
public function linkedContributions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Contribution', 'linked_id');
}
```

and retrieve the data:

```
$Resource = Resource::with(['contributions', 'linkedContributions'])->find(1);
```

3) other idea; you are currently able to link only 1 resource to another resource. If you create an extra table + hasMany 'linkedResources' relation, you will be able to link multiple resource back to the current Resource. (and skip this problem here altogether)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating a solution similar to your #1. I will post it here soon.